# What is the Log Event emitted for ENS when the resolving address is updated

Tags: javascript, ethereum

We're looking to build an indexer for all ENS records. Loading names is a simple task however determining the proper resolution address presumably requires reading the log events. I have seen AddressChanged emitted in ENS transactions but unsure if this is the correct log to use.

```
event AddressChanged(bytes32 indexed node, uint coinType, bytes newAddress);
```

Does anyone have experience with this sort of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddressChanged` event was introduced in the [EIP-2304](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2304) standard proposal (currently unfinished - April 2022), extending the original [EIP-137](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-137) ENS standard with multichain functionality.

So these are two separate events:

- `AddrChanged` introduced in the original EIP-137, emitted when a regular ENS record changes
- `AddressChanged` introduced in the EIP-2304 proposal, emitted when a multichain ENS record changes

ENS docs give a short description of both events: https://docs.ens.domains/contract-api-reference/publicresolver